# Validator in <noscript> causes JavaScript error

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation, graceful-degradation, noscript

The following .NET 3.5 code, placed in an aspx file, will trigger a JavaScript error when the page is loaded (for users who have JavaScript enabled):

```
<noscript>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txt_RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" 
      ControlToValidate="txt"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</noscript>
```

The error happens because the JavaScript generated by the ASP.NET validator control does not contain a null check on before the second code line below:

```
var ctl00_body_txt_RequiredFieldValidator =
  document.all ?
    document.all["ctl00_body_txt_RequiredFieldValidator"] :
    document.getElementById("ctl00_body_txt_RequiredFieldValidator");

ctl00_body_txt_RequiredFieldValidator.controltovalidate = "ctl00_body_txt";
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround to this?

---

*Footnote:* Why am I doing this? For my non-JavaScript users I am replacing some AJAX functionality with some different UI components, which need validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the following to the RequiredFieldValidator:

```
enableclientscript="false"
```

Seeing as you are using these in <noscript> tags, there is no point in supplying client side vaildation of the controls - they are only going to display if JS is turned off.

This will force the validation to happen (automatically) on the server side for you.

Just make sure you call "[Page.IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx)" before you process the response.

See [BaseValidator.EnableClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript is looking for an element contained in the noscript? AFAIK there's no clean way to detect script support from the server side.

I think you'll need to build in a redirect (I've seen this done with a meta-refresh in a header noscript if you don't mind a validation failure) to push noscript users to a "please turnscript on page" or do some surgery to loosen up the validation/control binding which may take some amount of wheel reinventing. This is one of those areas where asp.net's tight coupling between controller and view really punishes.